# Sorting a heterogeneous list of objects in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have some custom objects and dictionaries that I want to sort.  I want to sort both the objects the dictionaries together.  I want to sort the objects by an attribute and the dictionaries by a key.

```
object.name = 'Jack'
d = {'name':'Jill'}

sort_me =[object, d]
```

How do I sort this list using the object's name attribute and the dictionary's 'name' key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are almost certainly looking for is to use the key= option for sorted(), which provides a function which returns an arbitrary sort key for each element. This function can check the type of its argument and take various actions. For instance:

```
import types

class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.name = arg

def extract_name(obj):
    if type(obj) is types.DictType:
        return obj['name']
    else:
        return obj.__dict__['name']

d = { 'name': 'Jill'}    
print sorted([obj('Jack'), d], key=extract_name)
```

More information can be found on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys)

RichieHindle's suggestion of using isinstance is a good one. And while I was at it I thought it might be nice to support arbitrary element names instead of hardcoding 'name':

```
def extract_elem_v2(elem_name):
    def key_extractor(obj):
        dct = obj if isinstance(obj, dict) else obj.__dict__
        return dct[elem_name]
    return key_extractor
```

Which you can use like so:

```
print sorted(list_of_stuff, key=extract_elem_v2('name'))
```

Comment: +1. Minor suggestion: `isinstance(obj, dict)` would be neater, and would allow for classes derived from `dict`.

Comment: You're right, isinstance is a better choice there, not sure why I didn't think of that. Updated version appended to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack!  This answer is beautiful.

Comment: `__dict__` attribute is not available for all objects.

Comment: A) Corrections inline, that's what people read. The `type(..) is` thing has 0 merit to stay. B) is `vars(obj)` preferred over obj.__dict__? (vars is a less known builtin.)

Answer (score 3):

```
sort_me.sort(key=attr_or_itemgetter('name'))
```

Where `attr_or_itemgetter()`:

```
class attr_or_itemgetter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __call__(self, obj):
        try: return getattr(obj, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj[name]
```

NOTE: It intentionally doesn't check for dictionary type, therefore `attr_or_itemgetter('items')` applied to a dictionary will return `dict.items` method.

Comment: I find this answer more Pythonic than the one based on type-checking (may be a little slower if there are plenty of dicts in the sequence being sorted, but all it takes to optimize it for that use is flipping what's the try body & what's the except body, and catching different exceptions;-0).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Note that `sort()` does not return the sorted list, but `sorted()` does, so if you want to pass this to a template, you should use `sorted` in the parameters, or `sort` before you pass the list as a parameter.

```
itemized_action_list = list(chain(detection_point.insertbodyaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.insertheaderaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.modifybodyaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.modifyheaderaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.removebodyaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.removeheaderaction_set.all(),
                                  detection_point.redirectaction_set.all()))

sorted(itemized_action_list, key=attrgetter('priority'))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to be clear and precise in your examples. Without no additional info it is not possible to say what your list contains.

Answer (score 1):

new_list = [10,"m",20,30,"a","r",70,"d"]

def func(x):

```
if type(x) == str:

    return ord(x)+100

return x
```

new_list.sort(key=func)

print(new_list)

[10, 20, 30, 70, 'a', 'd', 'm', 'r']